# Track deleted internet history

Tags: firefox, internet, history

I have got a copy of the jumpListCache folder of firefox, which contains the favicon.ico files of deleted history. Is there a way to find the url of the site to which the each favicon belongs? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you talking about getting the URL from just the icon file?

If so, I don't think there's a way to do that (Though you *could* try a reverse image search and go from there, but I'm unsure if that would help very much).

Comment: reverse image search worked, thank you so much